# Installed Matplotlib using terminal on mac but ModuleNotFoundError in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I installed matplotlib using terminal on my mac and it was successfully installed. However, when I try to import matplotlib, it produces the ModuleNotFound error. The following are my codes and error messages.

Terminal:

```
(myProject) bash-3.2$ python3 -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cycler>=0.10 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /Users/zbao/.local/share/virtualenvs/myProject-opsBTjit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (45.2.0)

IDLE:

```
import matplotlib
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Thanks for the help! If anything else is needed please let me know. Sorry I am still very new to Python.

Comment: Are you definitely using the correct version of Python? Mac has the system python (2.7) by default. type `which python` in the terminal to see which one is being used.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Here is the messgae I get after I ran which python: /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of your traceback, it looks like you have installed `matplotlib` inside a `virtualenv`. So your choices are:

1. run your idle from your virtualenv: `myproject/bin/python3` then you should be able to `import matplotlib`
2. run `sudo pip install matplotlib`. This will install `matplotlib` into your system Python(2.7) so you can run from your system python. (`/usr/bin/python`)

Hope this helps

Comment: Nailed it, much appreciated mate!