# Why can I not run matplotlib on Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**My Issue.** I am trying to run matplotlib on python 3.10 on my MacOS, but I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

However, when I try running

```
pip install matplotlib
```

then I get back

```
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in ./mambaforge/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (8.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./mambaforge/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
```

Also, in response to

```
python3 --version
```

terminal says

```
Python 3.9.6
```

Also, I am able to use matplotlib just fine if I compile my code using Python 2.7.16 on Sublime Text 3.

**My Question.** How can I get matplotlib to run on Python 3.10?

Since I am still new to Python (or to programming, for that matter), please let me know if I should provide additional information.

Note: I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378173/installed-matplotlib-using-terminal-on-mac-but-modulenotfounderror-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106135/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-even-using-pip-install-matplotlib), but I couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe you should write `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: As you can see from all the requirements satisfied, matplotlib has been installed for python 3.9. You seem to have two versions of python 3 installed.

Comment: @Ambitions I tried that already. It didn't work.

Comment: @Reti43 That seems to be the case. I'm starting to think the installation issues are due to the fact that Python 3.10 is still a pre-release.

Comment: If you are a beginner to programming and python, and using macOS, I _strongly_ suggest using anaconda instead of pip (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue. It wasn't only for MatPlotLib, but Pandas and NumPy.

From seeing what the terminal tried to do, it seems that 3rd party libraries are not "compatible" yet. I am using my older version of python now.

When trying to get the libs, it just scrolled through all the versions of matplotlib, and gave errors. It might take some time before this is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I recently experienced this problem after installing Python 3.10.

Use version Python 3.9. That worked for me, but I can't figure out how to install matplotlib on 3.9 via the command line, but I'm using PyCharm right now, so I got it to work on there.

[proof of installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rye24.png)

If you figure out how to install it via the command line, let me know! I'm using two versions of Python. I would like to know how to do it as well. I'm sure I can find it eventually. I believe if you uninstall Python 3.10 and leave only 3.9, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary (unstable) fix for anyone desperate to run matplotlib (and many other packages, e.g. numba, scikit-learn, scipy, etc.) on Python 3.10 for Windows 10, as described by [Amit Thinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWnvBHb5R7A). Amit uses a source of unstable binaries curated by [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) at UC Irvine, so these are likely not malware infested.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue , while trying to install matplotlib for python 3.10 .
i faced 2 issues

1)It said wheel module not installed (installed via running pip install wheel)

2)It said it required microsoft visual c++ 14.0+ (it was already present when checked in control panel(x64)) (after installing wheel module while running the code[pip install matplotlib] for 3rd time). asked me to download visual studio community 2019 and build tools.... Did so.

And now i was able install matplotlib in python 3.10 and runs fine (when cheking in control panel there was another visual c++ 14.0+ installed (x86) along with (x64),dont know why it works only when x86 version of visual c++ is installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using conda enviroment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it does run on Python 3.10. When you are querying for a graph or plot, try doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issues with matplotlib,pandas,numpay etc on python 3.10 on window 10.
I install with windows binaries [packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

after download "matplotlib‑3.4.3‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl"
use this commond:

`pip install matplotlib-3.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`