# Pip cannot install anything after upgrading to Python 3.10.0 on windows

Tags: python, pip

I recently upgraded to the latest version of `python` version `3.10.0`  and upgraded `pip` also to the latest version `21.2.4`.

Now I cannot use `pip` to install anything. This is the error it gives for anything I try to install.

```
C:\Users\AMAL>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpemhtoti3'
       cwd: C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7
  Complete output (208 lines):
  setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
    warnings.warn(
  Running from numpy source directory.
  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\tools\cythonize.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
  Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
  Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
  Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
    libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_info:
    libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
    NOT AVAILABLE

  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\AMAL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1uxnt6o\numpy_5af9ff0d696c40848bc7d07b456797b7\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    FOUND:
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

  Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
  C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried downgrading both `python` and `pip` back but the issue still persists.
Also tried to create a `virtualenv` and in that also the same issue persists.

When I downgraded the following is the error

```
C:\Users\AMAL>python -m pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/57/3066077aa16a852f3da0239796fa487baba0104ca2eb26f9ca4f56a7a86d/torch-1.7.0-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl (184.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 184.0MB 67kB/s
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    dist = abstract_dist.get_pkg_resources_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\wheel.py", line 13, in get_pkg_resources_distribution
    return list(pkg_resources.find_distributions(
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\AMAL>python --version
Python 3.8.4rc1
C:\Users\AMAL>python -m pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/57/3066077aa16a852f3da0239796fa487baba0104ca2eb26f9ca4f56a7a86d/torch-1.7.0-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl (184.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 184.0MB 67kB/s
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    dist = abstract_dist.get_pkg_resources_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\AMAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\wheel.py", line 13, in get_pkg_resources_distribution
    return list(pkg_resources.find_distributions(
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\AMAL>python --version
Python 3.8.4rc1
```

I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to install the latest version of python and pip that supports libraries like `pygame` and `numpy`.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pytorch`?

Comment: Thats because most of the libraries didn't support python 3.10

Comment: this will help [NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458399/numpy-1-21-2-may-not-yet-support-python-3-10)

Comment: When you downgraded, did you confirm it worked with `python --version`?

Comment: oh  so not supported yet? How do we solve this for beginners.

Comment: I am taking a workshop for beginner to python and this issue is causing trouble.

Comment: `python --version` gives `Python 3.8.4rc1`

Comment: Which is what I had and worked fine.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the error after downgrading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to upgrade your pip**

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was I downgraded pip and python together. now it  works.

Comment: Anyone facing the same problem should take care to downgrade pip to `3.8.8` which is quite stable and upgrade `pip` to `20.0 `or above