# How to install OpenCV for Visual Studio Code & Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, opencv

- My python version = 3.10.0.
- My Visual Studio code version = 1.61.0
- I also tried downloading OpenCV
  (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.5.4/opencv-4.5.4-vc14_vc15.exe/download)
  and saved it in C:.
- I already have numpy installed by pip.

I tried using both my command prompt and terminal in Visual Studio code. I tried the following commands:
`pip3 install opencv-python`
`pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`

OpenCV successfully downloads, but does not install. However, both result in large error statements after the "installing build dependencies" step. I see
`Error Failed building wheel for numpy. Failed to build numpy Error: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project`

I would really appreciate help on resolving this issue. Please let me know if you want to see more of the error.

Comment: Numpy has not yet released a wheel for python 3.10. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465693/9177877

Comment: Is this numpy required to install opencv? I'm not able to install opencv. Thank you.

Comment: yes, numpy is a dependency for opencv.